# Cannot assign to 'click' because it is a 'method group'

Tags: c#, events

I'm using linux monodevelop to do c# stuff , what is wrong with this ?

?

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace aaadd
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            Button button = new Button();

            button.Click += new EventHandler (button_Click);
            win.Add (button);
            button.Show ();
            win.Show ();

            Application.Run ();
        }
        public static void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Error :

> Cannot assign to 'click' because it is a 'method group'

Comment: Try `button.Clicked += new EventHandler (button_Click);`

Comment: `Clicked` is the actual event, while with `Click` you can simulate a click by the user (in the end, `Click` fires the event `Clicked`). Pretty much every event is named in the "past simple" form of the verb to distinguish them from normal methods.

Comment: thank you @321polorex123 , please write it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To subscribe to the event you need to use

```
button.Clicked += new EventHandler (button_Click);
```